# object oriented design: using method parameters vs properties

Tags: c#, object-oriented-analysis

in object oriented design, Which  of the following is better?

sending parameters with method like :

```
obj.InsertRecord("raed","1987")
```

or using properties like :

```
obj.name= "raed"
obj.year= "1987"
obj.InsertRecord()
```

Comment: The question is which is more appropriate in this case. The former since the latter could fail when only one property was set but both are non-null fields.

Comment: if those are properties, they should follow [C# Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you send parameters, you'll have to alter the `InsertRecord()` signature every time the `obj`'s class signature changes (for example if you add a `description` property), given you will want to save those new properties.

Also the object itself should not be bothered with saving itself. That is not the object's responsibility. So, something like this is the most future-proof:

```
ObjectStorage.InsertRecord(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Object oriented programming, this is preferred: `obj.InsertRecord("raed", "1987");`

Component Oriented programming, the latter is preferred:
like this:

```
obj.name = "raed";
obj.year = "1987";
obj.InsertRecord();
```

Btw, this belongs to programmers.stackexchange